# Is there a way to rename all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

Ubuntu 16.04

I'm pretty new to linux and have a large number of files an the directory `dir`. These files have postfix `_uploaded`.

Is there a way to rename all this files and set them postfix `_handled` instead of `_uploaded`?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu has `rename` (`prename`), from directory `dir`:

```
rename -n 's/_uploaded$/_handled/g' -- *_uploaded
```

- `-n` is for `--dry-run`

After getting the potential changes to be made, remove `n` for actual action:

```
rename 's/_uploaded$/_handled/g' -- *_uploaded
```

---

You can also leverage `bash` parameter expansion, within a `for` loop over the filenames containing the string `_uploaded` at the end, from directory `dir`:

```
for f in *_uploaded; do new=${f%_uploaded}; echo mv -- "$f" "${new}_handled"; done
```

This will show you the changes to be made, remove `echo` for actual action.

Comment: The `rename` regex allows using `$` as "end of line" to make sure to replace only the suffix if a file was named like `A_foo_foo` - i.e. `rename 's/_uploaded$/_handled/' *` is to be preferred.

Comment: @Fiximan `rename` supports PCRE, but matching the end of the line using `$` is not the desired case here i am afraid.

Comment: I seem not to understand the question then: Isn't the aim to replace suffix A with suffix B?

Comment: @Fiximan The question does not mention anything about _suffix_, the pattern can be anywhere in the name AFAIU.

Comment: Might be a language barrier then: AFAIK suffix and and postfix are synonymous - but I'm not a native speaker though. [English guys seem to agree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81263/postfix-or-suffix)

Comment: @Fiximan duh..I'm really poor at this. Edited. Thanks.